# getting error while installing darkest theme in sts

Tags: java, eclipse, darkmode, sts

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 810cecf8ba271008.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 810cecf8ba271008.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 70b824d9a6b4ae29.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 70b824d9a6b4ae29.
OK
```

I've tried restarting & updating sts to but getting same error

Comment: The darkes theme plugin patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). If you don't like the built-in themes, there are other dark themes that are more ergonomic and don't do this.